# Installing php datastax driver on ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, cassandra, datastax, datastax-php-driver

I am trying to install the datastax php driver for Cassandra and when i run the following command:

```
pecl install ext/package.xml
```

after checking it out of git i get the following message:

```
configure: error: Unable to load libcassandra

ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/cassandra/configure' failed
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction in order to successfully install this driver please?

version of cassandra i am using is 2.1.8 so maybe the driver has not been updated to connect to the latest version of cassandra.

Comment: What does your `config.log` file say? Should be located in the directory where it is building in.

Comment: cc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'. not quite sure what im looking for config.log

Comment: any help would be much appreciated

Comment: what shell are you using? have you tried bash?

Comment: i havent tried bash as i thought the standard terminal is required.

Comment: When i start the cqlsh i get a native protocol once ive connected should that be thrift protocol?

Comment: i got this today as well

Comment: basically i need to have the c++ driver installed before i run the pecl command. im pretty convinced that thrift is the way forward but this is used as a workaround.

Comment: it seems the installation of the cpp-driver did not do the trick

Comment: https://medium.com/@Renjthvr/installing-php-7-0-cassandra-extension-driver-on-ubuntu-16-04-58781270eb07

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This has been resolved there was an issue with the incorrect php.ini not being referenced in phpinfo().

Answer (score 6):

The following steps worked for me. YMMV.

```
$ uname -a
3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.68-1+deb7u3 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Install some prereqs (removed `libuv-dev` from the list):

```
$ sudo apt-get install g++ make cmake libssl-dev libgmp-dev php5 php5-dev openssl libpcre3-dev
```

Trying to install `libuv-dev` right now will result in the following error:

> libuv depends on libc6 (>= 2.14); however:
>   Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.13-38+deb7u8.

Wheezy seems to have a slightly older version of `libc6`. Step up to Jessie to get 2.14. Add the following to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb-src ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
```

After running the following commands, these services will be restarted: mysql, exim4, cups, cron, atd, apache2

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install libc6
$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

Download and install the following files:

```
$ wget http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/14.04/libuv_1.6.1-1_amd64.deb
$ wget http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/14.04/libuv-dev_1.6.1-1_amd64.deb
$ wget http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/14.04/cassandra-cpp-driver_2.1.0-1_amd64.deb
$ wget http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/14.04/cassandra-cpp-driver-dev_2.1.0-1_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i libuv_1.6.1-1_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i libuv-dev_1.6.1-1_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i cassandra-cpp-driver_2.1.0-1_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i cassandra-cpp-driver-dev_2.1.0-1_amd64.deb
```

Download and install the DataStax Cassandra PHP extension:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/datastax/php-driver.git
$ cd php-driver
$ sudo pecl install ext/package.xml
```

Add the extension to `php.ini`:

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "extension=cassandra.so" >>/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini'
```

Restart Apache:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Confirm Cassandra appears using `<?php phpinfo();`