# pecl install cassandra throws: "error: Unable to load libcassandra"

Tags: php, cassandra, pecl, datastax-php-driver

```
pecl install cassandra
```

produces an error:

> configure: error: Unable to load libcassandra
>
> ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/cassandra/configure' failed

This error message is subject of another question here on SO, but has not been resolved: [Installing php datastax driver on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31838842/installing-php-datastax-driver-on-ubuntu)

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are missing cassandra C++ driver. I have run into the same issue on Ubuntu 14.04. I have done the following and it worked for me:

Prerequisites (Ubuntu 14.04):

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear php5-dev libgmp-dev libpcre3-dev g++ make cmake libssl-dev openssl
```

Download the following packages:

```
wget http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/16.04/dependenices/libuv/v1.8.0/libuv_1.8.0-1_amd64.deb
wget http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/16.04/dependenices/libuv/v1.8.0/libuv-dev_1.8.0-1_amd64.deb
wget http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/16.04/v2.4.1/cassandra-cpp-driver_2.4.1-1_amd64.deb
wget http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/16.04/v2.4.1/cassandra-cpp-driver-dev_2.4.1-1_amd64.deb
```

Install them in this order using dpkg:

```
sudo dpkg -i libuv_1.8.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libuv-dev_1.8.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cassandra-cpp-driver-dev_2.4.1-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cassandra-cpp-driver_2.4.1-1_amd64.deb
```

You should be able to install cassandra using pecl.
Don't forget to add `extension=cassandra.so` to your php.ini file and restart php process.

Based on an answer in the discussion you linked before.

Comment: How can fix this issue on os x?

Comment: I'm not familiar with os x. But I can't see package files for osx, so my guess would be you should build and install these packages [libuv, cassandra-cpp-driver] from sources

Comment: For ubuntu 14.0 you can use the following links

Answer (score 2):

This is how I got it to work (on debian):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y g++ git make cmake clang libssl-dev libgmp-dev php5-cgi php5-fpm php5 php5-dev openssl libpcre3-dev
sudo apt-get install libc6
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo curl http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/14.04/libuv_1.7.5-1_amd64.deb > /var/www/html/libuv_1.7.5-1_amd64.deb
sudo curl http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/14.04/libuv-dev_1.7.5-1_amd64.deb > /var/www/html/libuv-dev_1.7.5-1_amd64.deb
sudo curl http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/14.04/cassandra-cpp-driver_2.0.1-1_amd64.deb > cassandra-cpp-driver_2.0.1-1_amd64.deb
sudo curl http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/14.04/cassandra-cpp-driver-dev_2.0.1-1_amd64.deb > cassandra-cpp-driver-dev_2.0.1-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libuv_1.7.5-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libuv-dev_1.7.5-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cassandra-cpp-driver_2.0.1-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cassandra-cpp-driver-dev_2.0.1-1_amd64.deb
sudo pecl install cassandra
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried installing cassandra driver for php on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS for PHP 5.5.9 using 
[php-driver](https://github.com/datastax/php-driver/blob/master/ext/README.md#linuxos-x) and [cpp-driver](http://datastax.github.io/cpp-driver/topics/building/) as follows,

```
sudo apt-get install g++ clang make cmake libuv-dev libssl-dev git;
git clone https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver.git
mkdir cpp-driver/build
cd cpp-driver/build
cmake ..
make
```

and then,

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev php5 php5-dev openssl libpcre3-dev
pecl install cassandra
```

But got an error,

```
checking for supported DataStax C/C++ driver version... nawk: cannot open /include/cassandra.h (No such file or directory)
configure: error: not supported. Driver version 2.4.2+ required (found )
ERROR: /tmp/pear/temp/cassandra/configure' failed
```

after coping,

```
cp cpp-driver/include/cassandra.h /usr/include/
```

again got another one,

```
checking for cass_cluster_new in -lcassandra... no
configure: error: Unable to load libcassandra
ERROR: /tmp/pear/temp/cassandra/configure' failed
```

After doing lot of research, I got following simple solution,

```
sudo wget http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/14.04/dependencies/libuv/v1.8.0/libuv_1.8.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo wget http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/14.04/dependencies/libuv/v1.8.0/libuv-dev_1.8.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo wget http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/14.04/cassandra/v2.5.0/cassandra-cpp-driver-dev_2.5.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo wget http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/14.04/cassandra/v2.5.0/cassandra-cpp-driver_2.5.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libuv_1.8.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libuv-dev_1.8.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cassandra-cpp-driver-dev_2.5.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cassandra-cpp-driver_2.5.0-1_amd64.deb
```

Then just copy and enable extension,

```
sudo vim /etc/php5/mods-available/cassandra.ini
extension=cassandra.so;
php5enmod cassandra
```

Answer (score 1):

For ubuntu 14.04:
Installation steps are:

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear php5-dev libgmp-dev libpcre3-dev g++ make cmake libssl-dev openssl
wget downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/14.04/dependencies/libuv/v1.8.0/libuv_1.8.0-1_amd64.deb
wget downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/14.04/dependencies/libuv/v1.8.0/libuv-dev_1.8.0-1_amd64.deb
wget downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/14.04/cassandra/v2.4.2/cassandra-cpp-driver_2.4.2-1_amd64.deb
wget downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/14.04/cassandra/v2.4.2/cassandra-cpp-driver-dev_2.4.2-1_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i libuv_1.8.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libuv-dev_1.8.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cassandra-cpp-driver_2.4.2-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cassandra-cpp-driver-dev_2.4.2-1_amd64.deb

pecl install cassandra

ADD extension=cassandra.so in php.ini

restart the PHP process
```

Answer (score 1):

For CentOS 7. Installation steps are:

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum install automake cmake gcc gcc-c++ git libtool openssl-devel wget gmp gmp-devel boost php-devel pcre-devel git
pushd /tmp
wget http://dist.libuv.org/dist/v1.8.0/libuv-v1.8.0.tar.gz
tar xzf libuv-v1.8.0.tar.gz
pushd libuv-v1.8.0
sh autogen.sh
./configure
sudo make install
popd
popd
sudo curl http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/centos/7/dependencies/libuv/v1.8.0/libuv-1.8.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
sudo curl http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/centos/7/dependencies/libuv/v1.8.0/libuv-devel-1.8.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
sudo curl http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/centos/7/cassandra/v2.4.3/cassandra-cpp-driver-2.4.3-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
sudo curl http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/centos/7/cassandra/v2.4.3/cassandra-cpp-driver-devel-2.4.3-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh libuv-1.8.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh libuv-devel-1.8.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh cassandra-cpp-driver-2.4.3-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh cassandra-cpp-driver-devel-2.4.3-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum update
sudo pecl install cassandra
sudo yum update
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Docker's official PHP machine:

```
cd /tmp

apt-get install php-pear php5-dev libgmp-dev libpcre3-dev g++ make cmake libssl-dev openssl

php -r '$files = ["http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/14.04/dependencies/libuv/v1.8.0/libuv_1.8.0-1_amd64.deb", "http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/14.04/dependencies/libuv/v1.8.0/libuv-dev_1.8.0-1_amd64.deb", "http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/14.04/v2.3.0/cassandra-cpp-driver_2.3.0-1_amd64.deb", "http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/14.04/v2.3.0/cassandra-cpp-driver-dev_2.3.0-1_amd64.deb"]; foreach($files as $file) { copy($file, basename($file)); }'

dpkg -i libuv_1.8.0-1_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libuv-dev_1.8.0-1_amd64.deb
dpkg -i cassandra-cpp-driver_2.3.0-1_amd64.deb
dpkg -i cassandra-cpp-driver-dev_2.3.0-1_amd64.deb

pecl install cassandra

echo 'extension=cassandra.so' > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-ext-cassandra.ini
```

Then restart the container (`docker-compose restart ~~image~fpm~~`).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on Debian Jessie

```
apt-get remove libuv0.10-dev
git clone https://github.com/libuv/libuv.git
cd libuv
git reset --hard v1.19.1
sh autogen.sh
./configure
make
make check
sudo make install

git clone https://github.com/datastax/php-driver.git
cd php-driver
git submodule update --init
cd ext
./install.sh

vi /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Add extension=cassandra.so
php -i | grep cassandra
```

Answer (score 0):

for cantos Casandra 2.4.3 was deprecated, I updated perivious post:

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum install automake cmake gcc gcc-c++ git libtool openssl-devel wget  gmp gmp-devel boost php-devel pcre-devel git
pushd /tmp
wget http://dist.libuv.org/dist/v1.8.0/libuv-v1.8.0.tar.gz
tar xzf libuv-v1.8.0.tar.gz
pushd libuv-v1.8.0
sh autogen.sh
./configure
sudo make install
popd
popd
sudo wget http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/centos/7/dependencies/libuv/v1.8.0/libuv-1.8.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
sudo wget http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/centos/7/dependencies/libuv/v1.8.0/libuv-devel-1.8.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
sudo wget https://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/centos/7/cassandra/v2.8.0/cassandra-cpp-driver-2.8.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
sudo wget https://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/centos/7/cassandra/v2.8.0/cassandra-cpp-driver-devel-2.8.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh libuv-1.8.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh libuv-devel-1.8.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh cassandra-cpp-driver-2.8.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh cassandra-cpp-driver-devel-2.8.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm 
sudo yum update
sudo pecl install cassandra
sudo yum update
```