# pecl install cassandra throws: “error: Unable to load libgmp”

Tags: cassandra, pecl, php-7

I'm trying to use Laravel 5.1 and Cassandra 3.7

Version: PHP7, Apache2.2, Cassandra3.7

but, I got below error

```
configure: error: Unable to load libgmp
ERROR: `/var/tmp/cassandra/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config' 
failed
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: are you installing cassandra or php-driver? possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997871/pecl-install-cassandra-throws-error-unable-to-load-libcassandra OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31838842/installing-php-datastax-driver-on-ubuntu

Comment: @undefined_variable thank you very much!! complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are missing one of the dependencies which will allow the PHP driver to be successfully built and installed. Ensure you have GNUMP (with development headers) installed:

- RHEL: `sudo yum install gmp-devel`
- Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev`

If you run into any other missing dependencies or build issues I would recommend looking into the [build instructions on GitHub](https://github.com/datastax/php-driver/blob/master/ext/README.md) for the driver.